# Is there other ways to show reverse triangle inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, alternative-proof, absolute-value

I know that for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that  $$|x-y| \ge ||x|-|y||$$

which can be proven by writing $$|x|=|x+y+(-y)|$$ and $$|y|=|y+x+(-x)|$$ and applying triangle inequality.

But I am wondering if it could also be proven somehow by the following

Noting that $$|x|= max(-x,x)$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

and doing something like

$$|x+(-y)| \le |x|+|y| \ge |x|-|y|$$

and $$|y+(-x)| \le |y|+|x| \ge |y|-|x|$$

is there any wayI could do something like this for an alternate way of showing it
Thanks

Comment: Considering all four cases of the signs of $x,y$ yields a very straightforward proof.